# Making grep understand byte escapes

Tags: grep, unicode, character-encoding, escape-characters

I'm trying to match against some UTF-8 characters.
The problem is `grep` doesn't translate `\x` byte escapes, so
this fails:

```
echo -e '\xd8\xaa' | grep -P '\xd8\xaa'
```

while this succeeds:

```
echo -e '\xd8\xaa' | grep -P $(printf '\xd8\xaa')
```

Can grep understand byte escapes directly without using printf? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fails:

```
$ echo -e '\xd8\xaa' | grep -P '\xd8\xaa' | hexdump
```

This succeeds:

```
$ echo -e '\xd8\xaa' | grep -P $'\xd8\xaa' | hexdump
0000000 aad8 000a                              
0000003
```

#### Documentation

From `man bash`:

> Words of the form $'string' are treated specially.  The word expands to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as
>   specified  by  the
>   ANSI C standard.  Backslash escape sequences, if present, are decoded as follows:
>
> ```
>           \a     alert (bell)
>           \b     backspace
>           \e
>           \E     an escape character
>           \f     form feed
>           \n     new line
>           \r     carriage return
>           \t     horizontal tab
>           \v     vertical tab
>           \\     backslash
>           \'     single quote
>           \"     double quote
>           \?     question mark
>           \nnn   the eight-bit character whose value is the octal value nnn (one to three digits)
>           \xHH   the eight-bit character whose value is the hexadecimal value HH (one or two hex digits)
>           \uHHHH the Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is the hexadecimal value HHHH (one to four hex digits)
>           \UHHHHHHHH
>                  the Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is the hexadecimal value HHHHHHHH (one to eight hex digits)
>           \cx    a control-x character
> ```
>
> The expanded result is single-quoted, as if the dollar sign had not been present.

Comment: Why is there `-P` here? It's not necessary, is it? And do you know why Perl greps it without the `-C` switch, e.g. `perl -nlE"say if /\xd8\xaa/"` ?